# Double astrisk syntax & Help calling member functions

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm working a program where there's an Airline class. The Airline class contains a vairable to an array of dynamic Flight objects.

In the Airlines class I have (which can't be edited or changed, this was the header file given to me for the assignment):

```
//Airline.h    
class Airline {
public: 
    Airline();              // default constructor
    Airline(int capacity);  // construct with capacity n
    void cancel(int flightNum);     
    void add(Flight* flight);
    Flight* find(int flightNum);
    Flight* find(string dest);

    int getSize();


private:
    Flight **array;        // dynamic array of pointers to flights
    int capacity;          // maximum number of flights
    int size;              // actual number of flights

    void resize();
};
```

---

```
//Flight.h
    class Flight {
public:
    Flight();
    // Default constructor

    Flight(int fnum, string destination);     
    void reserveWindow();    
    void reserveAisle();
    void reserveSeat(int row, char seat);

    void setFlightNum(int fnum);

    void setDestination(string dest);

    int getFlightNum();

    string getDest();

protected:
    int flightNumber;
    bool available[20][4];    //only four seat types per row; only 20 rows
    string destination;
 };
```

I'm trying to impliment one of the find methods in the class.

for that, I have:

```
    Flight* Airline::find(int flightNum){
    bool found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(array[i].getflightNum() == flightNum){
            found = true;
            return array[i];
        }
    }

    if(!found)
        return 0;
}

// Return pointer to flight with given number if present, otherwise
// return 0.
```

But it's saying that I need a class type when trying to call the getFlightNum() method. I don't really understand the error. Am I not calling the method correctly? What is the correct syntax?

Comment: try `array[i]->getflightNum()`

Comment: You can also remove all instances of `found` from `Airline::find` since when you find the item you immediately return from the function. Therefore you also don't need the `if(!found)`, if you get to that point in the code then you haven't found the item and you don't need the check to `return 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are dealing with pointers instead of actual objects, try this:

```
if(array[i]->getflightNum() == flightNum){     // Notice I am using -> instead of .
    found = true;
    return array[i];
}
```